# How do I stop MySQL Installer from initializing every night at midnight?

Tags: mysql

Every night at midnight, this stupid annoying command prompt opens up and disrupts whatever I'm doing whether it's watching videos or playing games:

```
 =================== Start Initialization ===================
MySQL Installer is running in Community mode

Initializing product requirements
Loading product catalog
Checking for product catalog snippets
Checking for product packages in the bundle
Categorizing product catalog
Finding all installed packages.
```

I checked my Task Scheduler and deleted a MySQL task there, but it did not disable this. How do I fix this?